# convert list of lists to pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of lists, a sample of which is pasted below. I would like to convert this to a pandas data frame but the list contains many duplicates. How would I remove duplicates from a list of lists like this and convert to a data frame with two columns: `timestamp` and `price`?

```
[[{'timestamp': 1648558320942, 'price': 47876.0},
  {'timestamp': 1648558320942, 'price': 47876.0}],
 [{'timestamp': 1648558321945, 'price': 47881.0},
  {'timestamp': 1648558321945, 'price': 47881.0},
  {'timestamp': 1648558321945, 'price': 47881.0}],
 [{'timestamp': 1648558326768, 'price': 47876.0}]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can flatten the list and drop duplicates from your dataframe.

```
# import toolboxes
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain

# get data
data = [[{'timestamp': 1648558320942, 'price': 47876.0},
      {'timestamp': 1648558320942, 'price': 47876.0}],
     [{'timestamp': 1648558321945, 'price': 47881.0},
      {'timestamp': 1648558321945, 'price': 47881.0},
      {'timestamp': 1648558321945, 'price': 47881.0}],
     [{'timestamp': 1648558326768, 'price': 47876.0}]]

# flatten, create df and drop duplicates
a = list(chain.from_iterable(data))
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df = df.drop_duplicates()
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
       timestamp    price
0  1648558320942  47876.0
2  1648558321945  47881.0
5  1648558326768  47876.0
```

Comment: thank you @Pantelis that was spot on. If you dont mind could you explain how chain.from_iterable is working? I am new to python and would like to understand how this solution works

Comment: No problem, happy to help. As the name suggests, the `chain.from_iterable` function chains multiple iterables together. In this case the multiple iterables are the nested lists in data. Using the `chain.from_iterable` function we essentially unpack or flatten the nested lists into one list `a`.  This [guide](https://stackabuse.com/pythons-itertools-count-cycle-and-chain/) might also be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Just need to flatten out that list of lists:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[{'timestamp': 1648558320942, 'price': 47876.0},
  {'timestamp': 1648558320942, 'price': 47876.0}],
 [{'timestamp': 1648558321945, 'price': 47881.0},
  {'timestamp': 1648558321945, 'price': 47881.0},
  {'timestamp': 1648558321945, 'price': 47881.0}],
 [{'timestamp': 1648558326768, 'price': 47876.0}]]

newData = []
for each in data:
    newData += each

# or list comprehension
# newData = [each for v in data for each in v]


df = pd.DataFrame(newData).drop_duplicates()
```

And as a one-liner:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([each for v in data for each in v]).drop_duplicates()
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
       timestamp    price
0  1648558320942  47876.0
2  1648558321945  47881.0
5  1648558326768  47876.0
```

Answer (score 0):

**Quick answer:**

```
pd.DataFrame([item for sublist in my_list for item in sublist]).drop_duplicates()
```

**Explanation:**

1. Flatten list of lists
2. Create pandas DataFrame
3. Remove duplicates

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
list_of_dicts = [[{'timestamp': 1648558320942, 'price': 47876.0},
  {'timestamp': 1648558320942, 'price': 47876.0}],
 [{'timestamp': 1648558321945, 'price': 47881.0},
  {'timestamp': 1648558321945, 'price': 47881.0},
  {'timestamp': 1648558321945, 'price': 47881.0}],
 [{'timestamp': 1648558326768, 'price': 47876.0}]]
df = pd.DataFrame([i[0] for i in list_of_dicts])
print(df)
```